# Why is my MongoDB GeoJson query with index throwing error?

Tags: python, mongodb

Mongodb GeoJson queries with an index are not working and I can't figure out why. The error I am getting is:

```
Proj: {}
 planner returned error :: caused by :: unable to find index for $geoNear query, full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': 'error processing query: ns=sites_v1.sitesTree: GEONEAR  field=location maxdist=1.79769e+308 isNearSphere=0\nSort: {}\nProj: {}\n planner returned error :: caused by :: unable to find index for $geoNear query', 'code': 291, 'codeName': 'NoQueryExecutionPlans', '$clusterTime': {'clusterTime': Timestamp(1702483302, 11), 'signature': {'hash': b'\x87o\x04\x80! \xdc\xbf\x88\x0e\xf8/D\xbe\x18\xc8F\xe1Q\xa2', 'keyId': 7261788343090806786}}, 'operationTime': Timestamp(1702483302, 11)}
```

My `geoJson` field is labeled `location`.
I have a document in my collection with almost exactly the coordinates I am searching with.
The python script I used to add the index then later query it is:

```
from db_connect import get_database
# from pymongo import GEOSPHERE

dbname = get_database()

sites = dbname["sites"]

# sites.create_index(["location", "2dsphere"])

query = {
    "location": {
        "$near": {
            "$geometry": {
                "type" : "Point",
                "coordinates": [-86.592117, 31.179634]
            },
            "$maxDistance": 1000
        }
    }
}


# explain =  sites.find(query).explain()
# print(explain)
```

The indexes in the collection are:

[mongodb index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibGo3.png)
I've looked at the mongo docs and tried searching around SO.
https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/geo.html
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/indexes/index-types/geospatial/2dsphere/query/proximity-to-geojson/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't created the index that you're expecting. In your screenshot (please just paste the text output of `.getIndexes()` next time) we see the index is titled:

```
location_1_2dsphere_1
```

Based on the default naming conventions, this strongly suggests that the index which has been created has the following definition:

```
{ location: 1, 2dsphere: 1 }
```

Namely that it is a compound index where the second key is on a (non-existent) field called `2dsphere`. This isn't what you want and can't be used for your query. Instead you want:

```
{ location: "2dsphere" }
```

I *think* the syntax to do this in Python is as follows:

```
sites.create_index([("location", pymongo.GEOSPHERE)])
```

The direct shell syntax is:

```
db.sites.createIndex({location: "2dsphere"})
```

Comment: Thanks. Your suggestion worked and that is the correct python syntax.